# Comparing a geometric definition of cross product to the "usual" one

Tags: geometry, matrices, cross-product

Could you help me with my little problem?
Given this definition of cross product:

1) $a \times b$ is perpendicular to $a$ and $b$, whenever $ a,b$ are linearly independent

2) basis $a, \ b, \ a \times b$ is positively oriented

3) $\|a \times b\| = \|a\| \cdot \|b\| \cdot \sin( \angle(a, b))$

How can I prove that it's equivalent with the determinant definition of cross product (we put the basis vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ in the first row and the coordinates of $a$ and $b$ in the second and third rows)?

Comment: It sounds like a real chore to show the geometric definition implies the algebraic one, but it is not hard to do the other direction. I'm not even sure you can "prove" the algebraic definition, since the algebraic definitions are used to define the geometric ones (i.e. "two nonzero vectors are *defined* to be perpendicular when $a\cdot b=0$". Still it's an interesting question, and maybe I'm just too lazy to puzzle out that direction of the implication...

Comment: Remember the the "determinant definition" is not really a determinant and not a good way to "define" the cross product. It's just a trick to help you remember the formula for cross product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I've completely understood your question but here is how I would answer it

By definition, if the basis vectors are $\{\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k} \}$, the cross product of $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ (expressed in those basis vectors) is

$$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \end{array}\right| $$

For the first one, just change the basis vectors to $\{\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2},\vec{e_3}\}$ such as the two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are in the same plane given by the two vectors $\vec{e_1}$ and $\vec{e_2}$. Then they can be expressed as follows :

$$\vec{a}=(a'_1,a'_2,0) \quad \text{and} \quad \vec{b}=(b'_1,b'_2,0)$$

$$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\vec{e_1} & \vec{e_2} & \vec{e_3} \\
a'_1 & a'_2 & 0 \\
b'_1 & b'_2 & 0 \end{array}\right| = 
\left| \begin{array}{cc}
a'_1 & a'_2 \\
b'_1 & b'_2 \end{array}\right| \cdot \vec{e_3} $$

which is perpendicular to the plane and thus to $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

For the second one, choose your basis vectors such as $\vec{a} = a''_1\cdot\vec{e_1}$ with $a''_1>0$. Then we have

$$\vec{a}=(a''_1,0,0) \quad \text{and} \quad \vec{b}=(b''_1,b''_2,0)$$

$$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
a''_1 & a_0 \\
b''_1 & b''_2 \end{array}\right|=a''_1\cdot b''_2$$

As $a''_1$ is by definition positive, only the sign of $b''_2$ matters... And if you make a quick drawing of the situation, you directly see that the sign of

$$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\vec{e_1} & \vec{e_2} & \vec{e_3} \\
a''_1 & 0 & 0 \\
b''_1 & b''_2 & 0 \end{array}\right| = 
\left| \begin{array}{cc}
a''_1 & 0 \\
b''_1 & b''_2 \end{array}\right| \cdot \vec{e_3} = a''_1 \cdot b''_2 \cdot \vec{e_3} $$

is positive if they are positively oriented, and negative if not. As $\vec{e_3}$ is positively oriented in $\{\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2},\vec{e_3}\}$, that's it.

For the third one I'm not really sure, but as $$|\vec{a}.\vec{b}|=||\vec{a}||\cdot||\vec{b}||\cdot|\cos(\phi)| = |a''_1\cdot b''_1|$$ and that $$||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||=|a''_1\cdot b''_2| $$
I would do 
$$\begin{align}
(|a''_1\cdot b''_1|)^2+(|a''_1\cdot b''_2|)^2 &= (a''_1)^2\cdot [(b''_1)^2+(b''_2)^2] \\
||\vec{a}||^2\cdot||\vec{b}||^2\cdot|\cos(\phi)|^2 + (|a''_1\cdot b''_2|)^2 &= ||\vec{a}||^2\cdot||\vec{b}||^2 \\
(|a''_1\cdot b''_2|)^2 &= ||\vec{a}||^2\cdot||\vec{b}||^2 - ||\vec{a}||^2\cdot||\vec{b}||^2\cdot|\cos(\phi)|^2 \\
||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||^2&= ||\vec{a}||^2\cdot||\vec{b}||^2\cdot|\sin(\phi)|^2 \\
||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||&= \pm ||\vec{a}||\cdot||\vec{b}||\cdot|\sin(\phi)|
\end{align}$$

Then as previously, the sign of $a''_1 \cdot b''_2$ show you the sign of the cross product. And justifies the $\sin\phi$

$$||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||= ||\vec{a}||\cdot||\vec{b}||\cdot\sin(\phi)$$